# SharePoint search not finding all items in a list

Tags: 2010, list, search

I have a list with multiple items. One of the fields in the list is "Desk Number". Each item has a different desk number like 130 and 140.

When I am on the main site page and I search for 130 the results shows the list item.

If I search for 140 it does not show it.

If it matters, both searches find other results too. And it has been more than a week since both items were added to the list.

Anyone know why or what I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not sure why it would not work with search, but the following are some general suggestions.

- Make sure it was crawled after you added the items if you want to make sure search will pull it up
- If you are searching for specifically the desk number, you may want to consider configuring your result source on what it searches for
- Try using managed metadata if you have not already
- Depending on what you do, you may be able to approach it with simply showing a list view, and directing visitors to click filter by column values